# Does the "best_in_place" gem work with Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, best-in-place

I am struggling to get the "Best_In_Place" gem to work with Rails 6.  It shows the values but doesn't allow them to be edited.  Has any one got this working with Rails 6?

Comment: this gem appears to have been abandoned... the test suite covers up to Rails 5.1. If circumstances require you to use this with Rails 6, I recommend forking it, and getting the test suite passing with Rails 6. You could also look through the many forks of this gem to see if anyone has ported to Rails 6.

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to implement in Rails 6. **require('best_in_place') in application.js seems not to load this gem. Says **best_in_place is not a function** in console. Anyone help?

Comment: s. also solutions in https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/620#issuecomment-557881472